# Load only needed modules for a given class

Tags: python, class, python-module

I have a helper file, call it `helper.py` with three different classes `SQL,ML` and `AWS`.

Each class contains different helper-functions but not all of them need the same packages e.g `AWS` need the `boto3` module but `SQL` does not.

I have tried

```py
class AWS():
 def __init__(self):
   import boto3
   s3 = boto.client("s3")
 
 def magic():
   < do stuff with boto3>
```

but when I then call  `aws = AWS().magic()` I get "boto3 is not defined".

I could just include all of the packages in the very top of `helper.py` but I rather not

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace for that error message. If you `import boto3` inside `__init__`, then it will only be available inside `__init__`…

Comment: NameError: name "boto3" is not defined. How do you then import modules for at specific class if not in the `__init__`? Do you need to do it for each function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend splitting the file into three part.

```sh
- helper   # <-- make this as a folder
  - __init__.py
  - AWS.py
  - SQL.py
  - ML.py
```

In `__init__.py`

```py
from .AWS import AWS
from .SQL import SQL
from .ML import ML
```

If you want to use AWS in somewhere

```py
from helper import AWS
```

Comment: This way code becomes more modular & maintainable..

Comment: Does the `__init__.py` have to be there if `helper` is a submodule  in git?

Comment: It makes a folder python package regardless of git.